# UITableView add row from other Viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uitextfield

I have two view controllers one with the 3 tableviews and other controller I have a uitextfield and the text entered in the text field I want to add it to one of the tableview called ScheduleTableView in the other view controller.
Here is my code but I get the error unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an optional value at `vc.ScheduleTableView.beginUpdates()`

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: YTRoundedButton) {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondvc", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier  == "secondvc" {
        print(TitleTextField.text!)

        let vc = segue.destination as! GrowthMainViewController

        vc.ScheduleArray.append(TitleTextField.text!)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: vc.ScheduleArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        vc.ScheduleTableView.beginUpdates()
        vc.ScheduleTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        vc.ScheduleTableView.reloadData()
        vc.ScheduleTableView.endUpdates()



        TitleTextField.text = ""
        view.endEditing(true)

  }     
}
```

Comment: I tried also only calling a function when the button is pressed and update the tableview in the other view but didn't worked

Comment: Check the updated code, but still I have the same error

Comment: Unrelated to your issue but please note that variable and function names should start with lowercase letters. Class names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: I want the viewcontroller to update when button in the first view is pressed so where should I put the code in the second view without using `vc.AddSchedule() `

Comment: Like you said to me I passed the data using let `vc = segue.destination as! GrowthMainViewController

       vc.ScheduleTitle = TitleTextField.text!` to the other view but in the other view how can I update the view knowing that the button is pressed in the first view

Comment: Have you tried appending the text value to the array in prepare for segue instead of viewdidload?

Comment: @CaseyWest yes tried that, maybe the problem is that the array is not saved

Comment: @CoderJ13 is the scheduleArray a static variable? If not, make it one and try appending the value to the array in prepareforsegue.

Comment: @CaseyWest check my update question

Comment: @CoderJ13 make the array a global variable and see if that fixes the issue. I would not suggest this as a permanent solution, but more of a test to ensure the array is clearing itself. I will be able to create an example of a good way to do this later today without using a global var.

Comment: @CaseyWest made it a global same error, the error is not with the array, the error is with `vc.ScheduleTableView.beginUpdates()`

Comment: @CoderJ13 I feel like you are overthinking this. I just created a rudimentary version of this. All I did was append data to the array upon button press. I then use array.count in the numRowsInSection method. Thats it. If you want to email me your project I can take a look. Are you using CoreData or NSUserdefaults, etc. to store user data?

Comment: @CaseyWest yes sure there is the project  https://upload.cat/13ef9c04bd6b94e4 and I can email you the project

Comment: Done @CaseyWest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolution for this was changing where the array was declared (singleton is fine for this), and removing the unnecessary inserting, updating, reloading, etc.

The numRowsInSection method then calls the scheduleArray.count to show all corresponding data.

Before:

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: YTRoundedButton) {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondvc", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier  == "secondvc" {
        print(TitleTextField.text!)

        let vc = segue.destination as! GrowthMainViewController

        vc.ScheduleArray.append(TitleTextField.text!)
        let indexPath = IndexPath(row: vc.ScheduleArray.count - 1, section: 0)
        vc.ScheduleTableView.beginUpdates()
        vc.ScheduleTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        vc.ScheduleTableView.reloadData()
        vc.ScheduleTableView.endUpdates()



        TitleTextField.text = ""
        view.endEditing(true)

  }     
}
```

After :

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: YTRoundedButton) {
   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondvc", sender: self)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier  == "secondvc" {

        guard let text = TitleTextField.text else { return }
        scheduleArray.append(text)
        TitleTextField.text = ""
        view.endEditing(true)

  }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`vc.ScheduleArray.count - 1` is probably a negative indexpath

try this

```
if (vc.ScheduleArray.count - 1 >= 0){
    vc.ScheduleTableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: It's not a negative indexpath since I have 4 items in my array and I tried +1 still the same error.

Comment: tried it, same error found nil while unwrapping an optional value at  `vc.ScheduleTableView.beginUpdates()`

Comment: you should add a breakpoint at `vc.ScheduleTableView.beginUpdates()`, print out `TitleTextField.text!` and `vc`.  Something is nil and causing crashing.  You should also avoid using the bang operator as much as possible and unwrap them, nil values are the easiest ways to crash the app

Comment: that would defeat the purpose of learning how to debug, wouldnt it?  google how to add breakpoints and print out variables in your console.  it will make your life a hundred times easier

Comment: ill help you tonight if you havent figured it out

Comment: I did, printed `TitleTextField.text!` and `vc.array` they are not nil. The problem is with `vc.ScheduleTableView.beginUpdates()` maybe it is nil because it still didn't load...

Comment: if you remove beginUpdates, insertRows, and endUpdates does it crash and if it doesnt, does the tableview reflect your changes you want?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you trying to update a view controller inside of prepare function. Inside that function, the view is instantiated but it's Outlets are not connected yet.

To solve that issue, follow these steps:

On this method you should first update your model:

```
@IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: YTRoundedButton) {
   // update your model here

   self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "secondvc", sender: self)    
}
```

In your destination view controller, you should handle this model change and reload the table view's data.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```